# Make a Select All button of multiples CheckButton inside a ListBox

Tags: python, listbox, gtk, gtk3

i'm trying to make a list which each row has a checkButton and on top of this list i want a Select/Deselect All option. The problem is that i can't even figure it out how to iterate between the CheckButtons to use something like 'Gtk.CheckButton.Set_activate(True)'. I'm totally lost with this problem.

Here my code so far

```
class ListChapters(Gtk.Window):

def __init__(self):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="List of Itens")
    self.set_border_width(10)

    box_outer = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=6)
    self.add(box_outer)

    listbox = Gtk.ListBox()
    listbox.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE)
    box_outer.pack_start(listbox,False, False, 0)

    row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
    hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=50)
    row.add(hbox)
    label = Gtk.Label('Marcar/Desmarcar tudo.', xalign=0)
    checkall = Gtk.CheckButton()
    hbox.pack_start(label, True, True, 0)
    hbox.pack_end(checkall, False, True, 0)
    listbox.add(row)
    checkall.connect("toggled", self.mark_all)

    listbox2 = Gtk.ListBox()
    listbox2.set_selection_mode(Gtk.SelectionMode.NONE)
    box_outer.pack_start(listbox2, True, True, 0)

    index = ['Item1','Item2','Item3']

    for i in index:
        row = Gtk.ListBoxRow()
        hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=50)
        row.add(hbox)
        cap = Gtk.Label(i, xalign=0)
        check = Gtk.CheckButton()
        hbox.pack_start(cap, True, True, 0)
        hbox.pack_start(check, False, True, 0)
        listbox2.add(row)
        check.connect("toggled", self.on_check_marked)
```

Comment: keep all CheckButtons in list. And then you can iterate this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: Select All button of multiples CheckButton inside a ListBox
>   ... i can't even figure it out how to iterate between the CheckButtons

Basically you can do:

```
for boxrow in listbox2:
```

---

#### Gtk 3.0 (3.24.5) Documentation:

- [ListBox](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/ListBox.html#)
- [ToggleButton](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/ToggleButton.html#)
- [Gtk.SelectionMode](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/enums.html#Gtk.SelectionMode)

---

1. Define you own `ListBoxRow` inheriting from `Gtk.ListBoxRow`

   ```
   class ListBoxRow(Gtk.ListBoxRow):
       def __init__(self, label, **kwargs):
           super().__init__(**kwargs)
   ```
2. Define your widgets and make `self.check` a `class attribute`.

   ```
           hbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, spacing=50)
           self.add(hbox)

           cap = Gtk.Label(label, xalign=0)
           hbox.pack_start(cap, True, True, 0)

           self.check = check = Gtk.CheckButton()
           hbox.pack_start(check, False, True, 0)

           check.connect("toggled", self.on_check_marked)
   ```
3. Define a `class methode checkbutton(...` to **set** and **get** the `active state` of the `CheckButton`

   ```
       def checkbutton(self, state=None):
           print('checkbutton({})'.format(state))
           if state is True:
               self.check.set_active(state)
           elif state is False:
               self.check.set_active(state)
           else:
               return self.check.get_active()
   ```
4. To make `check.connect(...` happy ...

   ```
       def on_check_marked(self, event):
           print('on_check_marked({})'.format(event))
   ```

> **Usage**:

5. Add your `ListBoxRow(...` to `listbox2`

   ```
           for label in ['Item1','Item2','Item3']:
               row = ListBoxRow(label=label)
               listbox2.add(row)
   ```
6. Iterate `ListbBox` to set **all** `CheckButton` in `ListBoxRow` according to the passed `CheckButton active state`.

   ```
       def mark_all(self, checkbox):
           for boxrow in self.listbox2:
               boxrow.checkbutton(state=checkbox.get_active())
   ```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - gi.__version__: 3.22.0***

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked like a charm.
I didn't had the least idea how to tackle this problem. It was a eye opener create my own ListBoxRow, which also allows to get information of the activated Rows/CheckButtons (a problem i had yet to resolve). The other thing is that now i know how to iterate a ListBox.
As a biologist programing for a hobby i learned more than a asked for.
Thanks.